# SQL Logic for Multi-Matches

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where I am pulling back data from several tables MEMBERS, SS, and SSUSED. Where 'MEMBERS' is the table with member data, 'SS' is the table with the products that a member has purchased on their account and SSUSED is a table that stores the usage of the products. Products can have 1, 6 or 12 usages. So there can be a one to one, one to six, or one to twelve matching ratio. When I run my query, I am bringing back all of the usages. I only need to bring back the latest one (SSUSED.usedate).

I am also trying to filter out certain products and product categories and that doesn't seem to be totally working. I get a random product here and there and I can not seem to isolate the issue. I think it may be because my logic isn't written in a clean efficient manner.

CODE:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   MEMBERS.scancode, MEMBERS.lname, MEMBERS.fname, MEMBERS.mtypeid, MEMBERS.status, MEMBERS.lastvisit, MEMBERS.datejoin, 
   PRODUCTS.description, EMPLOYEES.lname AS EmpLname, EMPLOYEES.fname AS EmpFName, SSUSED.transactiontype, SS.initialdate, SS.initialquantity, 
   SS.usedquantity, MEMBERTYPES.mtype, SS.ssid, SSUSED.usedate
FROM PRODUCTCATS INNER JOIN
     PRODUCTS ON PRODUCTCATS.productcatid = PRODUCTS.productcatid INNER JOIN
     SS ON PRODUCTS.productid = SS.productid INNER JOIN
     MEMBERS ON SS.memid = MEMBERS.memid LEFT OUTER JOIN
     SSUSED ON SS.ssid = SSUSED.ssid INNER JOIN
     EMPLOYEES ON SSUSED.employeeid = EMPLOYEES.employeeid INNER JOIN
     MEMBERTYPES ON MEMBERS.mtypeid = MEMBERTYPES.mtypeid
WHERE        (SS.memid IN
                       (SELECT DISTINCT SS_1.memid
                         FROM            SS AS SS_1 INNER JOIN
                                                   SSUSED AS SSUSED_1 ON SS_1.ssid = SSUSED_1.ssid INNER JOIN
                                                   MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1 ON SS_1.memid = MEMBERS_1.memid
                         WHERE        (MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite) AND (SS_1.productid = '324' OR
                                                   SS_1.productid = '326') AND (SSUSED_1.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartDate AND @rvEndDate) AND (SSUSED_1.transactiontype = 'Use'))) AND 
                   (PRODUCTS.productcatid = '27' OR
                   PRODUCTS.productcatid = '28' OR
                   PRODUCTS.productcatid = '29' OR
                   PRODUCTS.productcatid = '58' OR
                   PRODUCTS.productcatid = '77' OR
                   PRODUCTS.productcatid = '75' OR
                   PRODUCTS.productcatid = '30' OR
                   PRODUCTS.productcatid = '61' OR
                   PRODUCTS.productcatid = '31' OR
                   PRODUCTS.productcatid = '32' OR
                   PRODUCTS.productcatid = '47' OR
                   PRODUCTS.productcatid = '68') AND (SS.productid <> '32' OR
                   SS.productid <> '335' OR
                   SS.productid <> '350' OR
                   SS.productid <> '618' OR
                   SS.productid <> '1312' OR
                   SS.productid <> '1646' OR
                   SS.productid <> '54987' OR
                   SS.productid <> '55937' OR
                   SS.productid <> '58289' OR
                   SS.productid <> '58876' OR
                   SS.productid <> '601691') AND (SSUSED.transactiontype = 'Use' OR
                   SSUSED.transactiontype = 'Expired') AND (SSUSED.usedate >= @rvStartDate)
```

Comment: It isn't totally clear what this is trying to do here but maybe TOP 1 order by SSUSED.usedate DESC? Or maybe you can user ROW_NUMBER? I would strongly recommend you start using aliases in your queries. It makes them a LOT easier to maintain.

Comment: You just have to change all this OR's to IN(value1,value2,value3..)

Comment: @sagi I was going to say the same thing..  Consider the following: `(PRODUCTS.productcatid IN ('27','28','29','58','77','75','30','61','31','32','47','68')) AND (SS.productid NOT IN('32','335','350','618','1312','1646','54987','55937','58289','58876','601691'))`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer the question but demonstrates how much cleaner this query can be with some formatting, aliases and converting those huge lists into IN predicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.scancode
    , m.lname
    , m.fname
    , m.mtypeid
    , m.STATUS
    , m.lastvisit
    , m.datejoin
    , p.description
    , e.lname AS EmpLname
    , e.fname AS EmpFName
    , su.transactiontype
    , SS.initialdate
    , SS.initialquantity
    , SS.usedquantity
    , mt.mtype
    , SS.ssid
    , su.usedate
FROM PRODUCTCATS pc
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS p ON pc.productcatid = p.productcatid
INNER JOIN SS ON p.productid = SS.productid
INNER JOIN MEMBERS m ON SS.memid = m.memid
LEFT JOIN SSUSED su ON SS.ssid = su.ssid
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES e ON su.employeeid = e.employeeid
INNER JOIN MEMBERTYPES mt ON m.mtypeid = mt.mtypeid
WHERE SS.memid IN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT SS_1.memid
        FROM SS AS SS_1
        INNER JOIN SSUSED AS SSUSED_1 ON SS_1.ssid = SSUSED_1.ssid
        INNER JOIN MEMBERS AS MEMBERS_1 ON SS_1.memid = MEMBERS_1.memid
        WHERE MEMBERS_1.siteid = @rvSite
            AND SS_1.productid in ('324', '326')
            AND SSUSED_1.usedate BETWEEN @rvStartDate AND @rvEndDate
            AND SSUSED_1.transactiontype = 'Use'
    )
    AND p.productcatid in('27', '28', '29', '58', '77', '75', '30', '61', '31', '32', '47', '68')
    AND SS.productid in ('32', '335', '350', '618', '1312', '1646', '54987', '55937', '58289', '58876', '601691')
    AND su.transactiontype in ('Use', 'Expired'
    AND su.usedate >= @rvStartDate
```

To actually be able to help with the question we need some understanding of what this is supposed to be doing and what isn't working.

Comment: The 'IN' clauses helped fix the issue with unwanted rows. THANK YOU!

Comment: The general purpose of the query is to return rows for the usage of two particular products (SS_1.productid in ('324', '326')). Then for each unique member in that list retrieve all products that were added to their accounts after the usage of those products. In essence we want to attempt to isolate members who bought a particular product, used it, and then bought other products because of it. HOWEVER, the multi-usage products are returning multiple rows. I just need the latest and greatest usage.

Comment: I can't begin to tell you how to do that because I have no idea what that means. Maybe you can utilize ROW_NUMBER here for this??